Comparison relation between $n$ and $C\log(n)$
I was reading the An analysis of model-based Interval Estimation for Markov Decision Processes, and at some point it is mentioned:

It is a well-known fact that for any constant $C >0, n \geq 2C\ln{(C)}$ implies $n \geq C\ln{(n)}$.

I'm having a hard time proving it. Can anyone help me out figuring it out? Doesn't seem hard given we know $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}^+, n \geq \ln{(n)}$

Remember to accept your favorite answer near the voting button. Otherwise welcome to Math S.E. :)

The statement is not too hard to prove if you use the fact that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $x > 2 \ln(x)$. This fact clearly holds for $x < e$, and it can be proved for $x \geq e$ by noting that the inequality is true at $x=e$, and the derivative of $x$ is greater than that of $2\ln(x)$ for all $x > e$.
I think your statement is easier to prove if we introduce $A = n/C$. After dividing everything through by $C$, we can then prove the following equivalent statement:

For any constant $C > 0$, $A \geq 2 \ln(C)$ implies $A \geq \ln(AC)$.

We first consider the case where $C \geq A$. This implies that $\ln(C) \geq \ln(A)$. Then
$$
\ln(AC) = \ln(A) + \ln(C) \leq 2 \ln(C) \leq A.
$$
Otherwise, we have $A > C$, and so we can use $\ln(A) > \ln(C)$ to get $\ln(AC) < 2\ln(A) < A$, using the fact given in the first paragraph.

Since $\ln$ is increasing, $C \geq A$ should imply $\ln(C) \geq \ln(A)$, not $\ln(C) \leq \ln(A)$, right?

Also this video was useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOqYfgEbns0

Thank you @riemmanianrascal! With the correction of kaba, it’s proved!

Thanks for pointing that out @kaba, I've fixed my answer!
